# find words with specific pattern and replace with its equivalent from a table list

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word, wildcard

I need to find words with the following pattern in one go:

1. started to [infinitive verb]
2. began to [infinitive verb]
3. started [progressive verb]
4. began [progressive verb]

For example:

1. started to arise
2. began to arise
3. started arising
4. began arising

Right now I am using two step method.

1. find the first word with wildcard pattern
2. then evaluate the second or third words to match any of the above four conditions

The VBA code is as follows:

```
Set AD = ActiveDocument.Range
With AD.Find
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "[sb][te][ag][ra][tn][e ]"
    Do While .Execute
        'here I evaluate the next word
    Loop
End With
```

Main purpose, is to change the the verb to its past form from a `table list`:

- started to arise REPLACE started arose
- began to arise REPLACE began arose
- started arising REPLACE started arose
- began arising REPLACE began arose

This is quite lengthy process (looping through individual instances then evaluating with a huge list), take a lot of time, therefore I am in search of finding any of two words 'Started' or 'Began', at the same time so that I can evaluate, if next word is 'progressive' or 'infinitive'.

Is this even possible to `FIND` with `OR` condition?
If not then what is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Your code is working as expected.  This means you have posted the question in the wrong forum.  You should instead post this question on Code Review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It should be a Code Review question

Comment: So I can delete this question here and ask it on code review?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is better suited to Code Review.

Comment: @AdrianMole it was already posted on CR and closed as off-topic. In the future, please don't use the existence of the Code Review site as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *Needs more focus*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353)